# Cumulative Area-Under-Curve above a cut-off value

Tags: r, machine-learning, auc

I am a non-computing/math student who is really new to R and require some help. I have provided a dummy dataset and example to illustrate my problems.

Note: AUC = area under curve; ICP = intracranial pressure; cumAUC = cumulative AUC;

To put things into context, any ICP value > 20 is not clinically-ideal. A method of calculating this physiological insult is via a measure known as the ICP-times-Time burden, which can be represented by the AUC of the ICP-Time curve above y-cutoff of 20.

Hence I would like to calculate the cumulative AUC of the ICP-time curve above a cut-off value of ICP = 20. However, my codes are not giving me the desired output because ideally, the cumAUC should remain constant at ICP values < 20 and not be increasing. Here's a dummy dataset and codes that I have created:

```
require(MASS) #Using the area function in MASS 
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(time=seq(1,20,by=1),
                 ICP=c(7,9,15,14,16,20,25,23,26,27,18,15,10,9,7,13,22,24,26,20))

ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x=time,y=ICP)) + geom_line() + geom_hline(yintercept = 20)

func_test <- approxfun(df$time, df$ICP, method="linear", rule=2)

area_single <- function(x) {area(func_test,0,x)}
area_multiple <- Vectorize(area_single)

area_cutoff <- function(x, level=20){
  tmp <- area_multiple(x)-lag(area_multiple(x))-level*(x-lag(x))
  tmp_test <- tmp>0
  tmp_test <- ifelse(is.na(tmp), FALSE, tmp_test)
  out <- ifelse(tmp_test, tmp, 0)
  return(out)
}

df_auc <- df %>%
  mutate(cumAUC = cumsum(area_cutoff(time)))
```

Could you all kindly point out any possible error in my code, or any alternative suggestions will be great! :) Thank you so much for your help; much appreciated!